# How to show a bootstrap modal popup in angular 5 when clicking a button in different component and bind a data in modal popup

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4, angular5

I have two component , in one component i have a button and in other component i have a popup which is bootstrap modal popup. i need to popup this modal popup and bind a data in that popup when click on this button. can you guys show me a example or sample project how to show popup and data transfer between two components.

```
<div id="parentdiv">            
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" (click)="submit()">Submit</button> 
     <popup></popup>
</div>

  ngOnInit(){    
    this.commservice.attachSubscribers(['popupevent']);     
     this.commservice.getSubscriber('popupevent').subscribe((data) => {
       this.rolesList = data; 
       const modalRef = this.modalservice.open(guidanceComponent);
       modalRef.componentInstance.data = this.rolesList;
     })      
  }
```

Comment: How are these components related. Are they nested or siblings?

Comment: nested. <parentdiv><second></second></parentdiv>

Comment: you can use @ViewChild to access child and call methods on it. do you mind showing some code?

Comment: i have used service to communicate between components.

Answer (score 0):

In your parent component

```
@ViewChild(Popup) popup: Popup;
click() {
  this.popup.showModal(newData)
}
```

your child component

```
showModal(newData) {
this.oldData = newData;
//code to show modal etc
}
```

You can find more help at: https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/

Comment: What is Popup?. Is it my childcomponent name

Comment: if possible Can you please give me a sample example?.

Comment: Popup is your child component.

Comment: @sreeraj i have added link to example.

Comment: Hai can you please tell me how to show the bootstrap modal popup?

Answer (score 0):

steps :

1. Make your pop up a seperate parent component.
2. use output component to track the child click event and fire parent
   method to open pop up using event emitter. Also you can send data
   using output event.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps you :

ParentComponent.html:

```
<div id="parentdiv">            
   <button type="button"  (click)="addEditHandler($event)"> Submit </button> 
     <popup *ngIf="showModal" (OnCloseModal)="closeModal()" 
     [getModelId]="modelDataItem" > 
     </popup>
</div>
```

parentComponent.ts:

```
     public showModal: boolean = false;
        public modelDataItem: any = {};
    
        // Send Id for New or Edit ------------------------
   public addEditHandler({ dataItem }) {
     this.modelDataItem=(typeof dataItem=="undefined") ? {Id: 0} : {Id: dataItem.Id };
     this.showModal = true;
         }
     // Close Modal ---------------------------------
      closeModal() {
        this.showModal = false;
      }
```

popup Component.html:

```
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body p-0">
                 <button mat-button  (click)="onCancel()"> close Modal</button>
                   //your code ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

popup Component.ts

```
// Get data From Parent ----------------------------------
      @Input() public set getModelId(_model: any) {
        if (_model != undefined) {
          //get data ...........
        }
      }

 // Close Modal ----------------------------------
   @Output() public OnCloseModal: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
   onCancel() {
     this.OnCloseModal.emit(true);
   }
```